# Material stretching/scaling inconsistently across objects with scaling applied and identical texel density

Tags: materials, uv

This is an ongoing issue with multiple models/materials, but I finally got frustrated enough to make a forum post. Using Blender 3.4.1, on objects with Scale applied (showing 1,1,1 in the Transform menu), and unwrapping all of the objects in the same UV window to apply consistent texel density, I still see my materials scaled wrong across the object and/or stretched.

I have tried checking forums and tutorials, and they all tell me the same thing: "Apply Scale!" which I have already done as you can see verified by my screenshots.
[image]
[image]
[image]

If I scale the stretched object down, the material is no longer stretched, and it doesn't change if I then apply scale!
[image]

Again, if I go into the UV editor and do a Smart UV Project OR unwrap with Project From View and Set My TD, the scaling/stretching does not change.
[image]

My material is just a Principled BSDF with a noise texture going to roughness and normal.
[image]

What am I doing wrong or missing? It genuinely feels like I'm taking crazy pills.

SOLUTION:
Texture coordinate+mapping node, scaling is now consistent across parts.
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you have the built-in Node Wrangler addon activated select on one of the Noise Texture nodes and hit Ctrl-T. That should add Texture Coordinate and Mapping nodes. Connect the Vector output of the Mapping node to both Noise texture inputs and the Texture Coordinate UV output into the Vector input of the Mapping node. Does that improve matters?

Comment: That did it, thank you so much. Adding pics of results and the updated nodes for whoever finds this later down the line.

Comment: Good! It's a more or less standard step in most texturing tutorials, although the output used on the Texture Coordinate does vary depending on its use.